# Comparar 2 arrays e criar um novo array se tiverem o mesmo Id

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho 2 arrays:

```
array1 = [
...
  {
   "id_projeto": 4,
   "sigla": "ADM-APR",
   "nome": "Administração APR",
   "descricao": null,
   "atividades": [ 13, 14, 49, 80, 81, 82 ] // id
  }
...
];

array2 = [
...
  }
    "id_atividade": 49, //id
    "codigo": "P46",
    "nome": "Treinamento de Instalação e Manutenção",
    "data_inicio": "2017-04-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-04-30",
    "prioridade": "1 ",
  },
  }
    "id_atividade": 50, //id
    "codigo": "P47",
    "nome": "Manutenção das estações",
    "data_inicio": "2017-04-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-04-30",
    "prioridade": "1 ",
  }
...
];
```

Tenho que criar um novo array com as atividades(array2) de cada projeto(array1), ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
array3 = [
...
  {
    "sigla": "ADM-APR",
    "nome_projeto": "Administração APR",
    "descricao": null,
    "id_atividades": [ 13, 14, 49, 80, 81, 82 ],
    "atividades": [
      {
       "id_atividade": 49,
       "codigo": "P46",
       "nome": "Treinamento de Instalação e Manutenção",
       "data_inicio": "2017-04-01",
       "data_fim": "2017-04-30",
       "prioridade": "1 ",
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
...
];
```

---

```
array3 = array1.atividades.map(obj => {
        array2(ativ => {
            if(obj == ativ.id_atividade){
                return console.log(ativ)
            }
        })
    });
```

Ao retornar o resultado no console.log, a resposta é a esperada, ao retornar a resposta o array recebe o numero de atividades corretas, mas, undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes copiar cada objeto na array para evitar mudar dados fora deste mapeamento, e depois mapear a propriedade `atividades` uma a uma procurando em `array2` pelo objeto correspondente usando o `.find()` que retorna o elemento que verificar a condição `iterado.id_atividade == id_procurada`.

```js
var array1 = [{
  "id_projeto": 4,
  "sigla": "ADM-APR",
  "nome": "Administração APR",
  "descricao": null,
  "atividades": [13, 14, 49, 80, 81, 82] // ids
}];

var array2 = [{
    "id_atividade": 49, //id
    "codigo": "P46",
    "nome": "Treinamento de Instalação e Manutenção",
    "data_inicio": "2017-04-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-04-30",
    "prioridade": "1 ",
  },
  {
    "id_atividade": 50, //id
    "codigo": "P47",
    "nome": "Manutenção das estações",
    "data_inicio": "2017-04-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-04-30",
    "prioridade": "1 ",
  }
];

var array3 = array1.map(obj => {
  const novoObjecto = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); // cria uma cópia
  novoObjecto.id_atividades = novoObjecto.atividades; // guardar a array de IDs original
  novoObjecto.atividades = novoObjecto.atividades.map(id => array2.find(el => el.id_atividade == id));
  return novoObjecto;
});

console.log(array3);
```

Usando o segundo exemplo do teu código ficaria assim:

```js
const atividadesList = [{
    "id_atividade": 1,
    "codigo": "P1",
    "nome": "Operação SEMANAL do marégrafo convencional da EMFOR (CE)",
    "data_inicio": "2017-01-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-01-31",
    "prioridade": "1 "
  },
  {
    "id_atividade": 39,
    "codigo": "P1",
    "nome": "Operação SEMANAL do marégrafo convencional da EMFOR (CE)",
    "data_inicio": "2017-02-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-02-28",
    "prioridade": "1 "
  },
  {
    "id_atividade": 6,
    "codigo": "P1",
    "nome": "Operação SEMANAL do marégrafo convencional da EMFOR (CE)",
    "data_inicio": "2017-06-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-06-30",
    "prioridade": "1 "
  },
  {
    "id_atividade": 32,
    "codigo": "P1",
    "nome": "Operação SEMANAL do marégrafo convencional da EMFOR (CE)",
    "data_inicio": "2017-07-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-07-31",
    "prioridade": "1 "
  },
  {
    "id_atividade": 28,
    "codigo": "P1",
    "nome": "Operação SEMANAL do marégrafo convencional da EMFOR (CE)",
    "data_inicio": "2017-08-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-08-31",
    "prioridade": "1 "
  },
  {
    "id_atividade": 19,
    "codigo": "P1",
    "nome": "Operação SEMANAL do marégrafo convencional da EMFOR (CE)",
    "data_inicio": "2017-09-01",
    "data_fim": "2017-09-30",
    "prioridade": "1 "
  }
];

const atividadesId = [10, 19, 28];


const atividades = atividadesId.map(
  id => atividadesList.find(obj => obj.id_atividade == id) || {}
);
```

Comment: Estou tentando fazer isso dentro de uma mutations no vuex, não consegui ainda, mas já me deu alguma ideia. Vlw !

Tem alguma dica de artigo, tutorial, video, qualquer coisa que me ajude a trabalhar melhor com arrays em javascript ? Sempre tenho dificuldade com isso.

Comment: @mtAlves se estás a usar Vue.js/Vuex explica a pergunta melhor. Mostra como estão as `actions` e as `mutations` e o que queres fazer. Se cada ID for buscar por ajax o elemento correspondente deves fazer nas `actions` pois as `mutations` devem somente ter código síncrono.

Comment: Na verdade eu estou começando a usar o vuex agora e comecei com desenvolvimento web vai fazer 3 meses, então ta tudo meio bagunçado e eu ainda estou meio perdido kk, mas da uma olhada github.com/mtAlves/pta

Comment: @mtAlves eu uso o Vue no trabalho e acho excelente. Acho contudo que esta pergunta não vai dar para perceberes tudo. A app é grande? Precisas mesmo do Vuex? Pode ser caso de ser mais fácil começar sem Vuex...

Comment: Uma app média, mas talvez se torne grande. Não tenho certeza se preciso do Vuex, mas como estou querendo aprender, achei interessante começar a utilizá-lo. E sim, Vue é excelente, eu nunca tinha escrito nem uma linha de css a 3 meses atrás e já consigo desenvolver alguma coisa, mesmo que dando cabeçada kkk

Comment: @mtAlves ok. Então sugiro ires perguntando aqui passo a passo, há mais gente aqui que também sabe de Vue.js e pode ajudar. Em relação à pergunta, diz o que não conseguiste usar/compreender para ficar este problema resolvido.

Comment: Consegui, mas o console.log imprime o resultado esperado, porem os dados ficam como undefined. Vou editar a pergunta pra visualizar melhor.

Comment: @mtAlves nesse caso tens uma condição assíncrona que não estás a respeitar.

Comment: @mtAlves vi agora o teu edit. Não estás a usar o meu código. Coloca aqui um jsFiddle com esse código todo que posso dar uma olhada e corrigir

Comment: Não consegui fazer no jsFiddle, se puder da uma olhada no codigo depois lá no github (https://github.com/mtAlves/pta/blob/master/src/store/mutations.js), subi o rest fake q eu to usando com o json-server tb (server.json). Vou dormir um pouco. Mas valeu pela força de qualquer forma.

Comment: @mtAlves então no caso de não haver ID queres retornar `''` ou `{}`. Retornar `{}` ou remover da array parece-me mais correto que retornar `''`

Comment: Fiz no pythontutor https://goo.gl/Z3oUFW  mesmo olhando frame a frame não consigo entender o pq retornar undefined, eu esperava que me retornasse o objeto inteiro.

Comment: @mtAlves viste a minha ultima pergunta aqui?

Comment: @mtAlves editei a resposta com um novo exemplo, usei um objeto vazio quando não encontrar

Comment: Funcionouuuuuuu, acho que eu te amo cara. Não tinha pensando no  find(). Obrigado de verdade!!

Comment: @mtAlves ótimo. Eu tinha usado o `find` no primeiro exemplo que tinha dado, mas agora com o segundo exemplo talvez tenha ficado mais claro. Fico contente de ajudar :)